# Adding a dependency to a gretty task

Tags: gradle, build, gretty

I'm using [the gretty plugin](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/index.html) in Gradle.

It works, I can list the tasks, for example `appRun`, and execute them.

But the tasks aren't found when I try to add a dependency with

```
apply plugin 'war'
apply from: 'https://raw.github.com/akhikhl/gretty/master/pluginScripts/gretty.plugin'

transpileScss << {
    ...
}

tasks.appRun.dependsOn transpileScss
```

I get:

```
Could not find property 'appRun' on task set.
```

What happens? How can I add a dependency to tasks of the Gretty plugin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your logic into a closure and pass it to `project.afterEvaluate`:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
   tasks.appRun.dependsOn transpileScss
}
```

Gretty tasks are added no sooner than project is evaluated.