# Gretty: How do I specify path to war file?

Tags: gradle, jetty, war, gretty

I am using Jetty Gradle plugin, and trying to port my script to use Gretty.
The following works with Jetty Gradle plugin:

```
jettyRunWar {
    // do not use "war" task, use myCustomWarTask
    dependsOn myCustomWarTask
    dependsOn.remove("war")

    webApp = myCustomWarTask.archivePath
}
```

Ho do I achieve the same in Gretty?

Comment: As far as I see gretty doesn't work that way. You can run the application from the source code directly.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want some pretty basic gretty setup:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:1.4.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'

gretty {
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'

    httpEnabled = true
    httpPort = 8081
    contextPath = '/WebServer'
    jvmArgs { '-ea' }

    loggingLevel = 'ALL' // options:   'ALL', 'DEBUG', 'ERROR', 'INFO', 'OFF', 'TRACE', 'WARN'
}
```

Once you have that, you can setup a [webapp](http://akhikhl.github.io/gretty-doc/Farm-web-app-list.html#_file_based_web_app_references) in a farm.  Specify the path to your war file here (the provided example is where the GWT plugin is putting mine).

```
farm {
    webapp 'build/libs/web_server.war'
}
```

To specify the [dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960409/adding-a-dependency-to-a-gretty-task):

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    tasks.farmRun.dependsOn myCustomWarTask
}
```

Once you have all this in place, 'gradle farmRun' will build and run your war file in Gretty.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else has run into this recently, but for the sake of posterity, I just use:

```
gradlew appRunWar
```

There is also support for farms using:

```
gradlew farmRunWar
```